# I can't install any Linux distro on my laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have wanted to put some Linux operating system on my old laptop for a while now, however literally ALL distros do not work. I am a Windows 7 user and it runs normally on this system for some reason.

From Arch Linux to Ubuntu (Gnome to XFCE), none of them work, they always restart my computer as if it had an overheating problem but nothing is wrong, even when I check.

**I intend to use only Linux as the main operating system.**

My laptop is quite old, an Acer Aspire 4752.

## Specs:

Intel i5 2450M (Dual Core 2.5GHz);

Graphics HD 3000;

4GB RAM (2x2);

750GB Hitachi HDD;

[Motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35DM1.png).

#### Edit 1:

The problem with rebooting occurs right after booting, sometimes right on the Live CD, and sometimes on the system itself after installing. The interval is always between 1 and 2 minutes on the system, and using "**nomodeset**" I managed to extend the time to almost 4 hours, but it would be unfeasible to use the systems using nomodeset. I have tried reinstalling the video drivers even in nomode, but it didn't work the same way.

Comment: What do you mean “restart your computer”? Kernel panic? If it is happening to all distros, you have a hardware issue - how have you verified it isn’t overheating?

Comment: I checked with a temperature monitor, it was not going over 55°C in the processor or other parts. This problem only occurs when using a Linux distribution, not even Windows 10 which is much heavier occurs this problem.

Comment: With an i5 processor that will be an early UEFI system. Do you have latest update to UEFI firmware, even if now older? Many early UEFI had issues. Are you installing UEFI or BIOS boot mode to gpt or MBR partitioned drive? If only Ubuntu often better to use gpt, but that requires either an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot or a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. What version of Ubuntu 20.04? Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Yeah... My BIOS is up to date, as the image I left attached the latest version is the 2.15. , here are my settings (Only the ISO is as Archcraft, but the settings are the same). https://imgur.com/lNKUeWe

Comment: I don't see any specifics as to what Ubuntu/Xubuntu product you're using, nor any clues as to what validation if any you performed to validate the ISO before write, or write of ISO to media for your *unstated* release of Ubuntu; thus if you ruled out user-errors or thumb-drive issues. Please be specific.   *your description also highlights hardware errors with no clear indication you ruled out such errors, nor if you explored logs, used SysRq keys to explore kernel etc*